# Разбор числа на массивы

Tags: python

Есть переменная `a = 1000`, нужно чтобы происходила проверка на равенство, задача "Счастливого билета", то есть, левая пара чисел должна совпадать при умножении со второй парой: `1*0 == 0*0`. Решил делать это через массивы и сталкиваюсь с тем, что нужно как-то превратить тип `int` в `list`, чтобы потом можно было вызывать массив по индексам и перемножать.

Выводит:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [65]: l = list(map(int, str(a)))

In [66]: l
Out[66]: [1, 0, 0, 0]

In [67]: l[0] * l[1] == l[-2] * l[-1]
Out[67]: True
```

Comment: Спасибо большое\